# How to generate Long class type variable from xsd in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am generating my model classed using xsd, following is one of my xsd file, using which I am generating `Generator` model, here my problem is i want the type of one of the variable is `Long` class type but I am getting `long` premitive datatype.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="1.0">
<xsd:complexType name="Generator">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="timestamp" type="xsd:long" minOccurs="1" />
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Generated Class is like:-

```
public class Generator
implements Cloneable, CopyTo, Equals, ToString
{

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String id;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected int age;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected long timestamp;
// settter and getter methods
}
```

generated `timestamp` value is of type `long` but I want it of type `Long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came over similar issue few days back. After playing around with xsd, I found out the below two points:

1. If the attribute is required, then xjc will generate with primitive types e.g. int, long
2. If the attribute is optional, then you will have Object type e.g. Integer, Long, etc.

It is making sense as required field will need to have default value. Coming back to your case, if you want `timestamp` is Long, then remove `minOccurs`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue in my XSD as well, whereas i need object instead of primitive.

for your case just try option 4 given below. It should work as it did work for me as well.

1. type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >(Generates)- Long value (object)
2. type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" >(Generates)- JAXBElement value (object)
3. type="xs:long" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >(Generates)- long value (primitive)
4. type="xs:long" **minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable**="true" >(Generates)- **Long value** (object)

I know it's very late reply but it may help somebody else who is facing such issues.